# Django: How to select the Columns and its values for Max and Min values from each row in a table?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-orm

I have a table with this shape:

```sql
id | origin |    ABC     |    DEF     |   .....  |  XPTO
 1 |   ABC  |     0      | a number   | a number | a number 
 2 |   DEF  |  a number  |     0      | a number | a number
```

As you can see, the values in origin column, are also columns. And every time a origin match a column, the value is 0. (This represents distances, so from itself the distance is 0).

So I need to retrieve, for each row, the min and max values (excluding the value 0, greater than works) and also the columns containing the values.

For e.g, for the following table:

```
id | origin |    ABC     |    DEF     |   GHI    |   XPTO
 1 |   ABC  |     0      |    10.2    |   2.5    |   27.0
 2 |   DEF  |    45.8    |     0      |   20.34  |    4.0
...
```

Would be perfect if the query returns a list of dictionaries like this:

```
[
 {'origin': 'ABC', 'GHI': 2.5, 'XPTO': 27.0},
 {'origin': 'DEF', 'XPTO': 4.0, 'ABC': 45.8},
 ...
]
```

Comment: Are you select the value column basis? why ABC and DEF column not get?

Comment: What do you mean by not get? Sorry, I didn't get your point.

Comment: That's not possible, a SQL query always returns the same columns for all the rows it fetches. You can annotate it with the min and max values, but not with the keys of the columns.

Comment: Normalized data model would simplify this task a lot.